# How to focus text area from one div to another div using arrow key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my div structure and I want to move my cursor from one div to another div using arrow up and down key. Is there any solution?

```
<div id="InsertDiv">
    <div draggable="true" onclick="openPropDyn(event)" data-serial="6018" ondragstart="drag(event,6018)" class="subtaskDetailDive complete" id="subtaskDetailDive6018">
        <div class="subtaskRow" id="readOnlyID6018">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div draggable="true" onclick="openPropDyn(event)" data-serial="6019" ondragstart="drag(event,6019)" class="subtaskDetailDive complete" id="subtaskDetailDive6019">
        <div class="subtaskRow" id="readOnlyID6019">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div draggable="true" onclick="openPropDyn(event)" data-serial="6020" ondragstart="drag(event,6020)" class="subtaskDetailDive complete" id="subtaskDetailDive6020">
        <div class="subtaskRow" id="readOnlyID6020">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div draggable="true" onclick="openPropDyn(event)" data-serial="6021" ondragstart="drag(event,6021)" class="subtaskDetailDive complete" id="subtaskDetailDive6021">
        <div class="subtaskRow" id="readOnlyID6021">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div draggable="true" onclick="openPropDyn(event)" data-serial="6022" ondragstart="drag(event,6022)" class="subtaskDetailDive complete" id="subtaskDetailDive6022">
        <div class="subtaskRow" id="readOnlyID6022">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that if you are overriding arrow keys when the textarea is in focus, you will not be able to use the same keys to navigate the caret within element.

Comment: yes @Taplar. there is a contenteditable div.i want to move one from another using arrow keys. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407093/focus-the-next-input-with-down-arrow-key-as-with-the-tab-key

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dMJvv/1/ Check this

Comment: i need to move from one div to another div not input, i can handle input navigation using event. Thanks @slacker

Comment: Which one is the contenteditable div?  I don't see that in your example.

Comment: textarea will be contenteditablediv @Taplar

Comment: Huh?  textareas are already editable...  Or you mean the div around the textarea?

Comment: this text area will replace by a contenteditable div

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).keydown(
  function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      $(".move:focus").closest('.subtaskDetailDive').next().find('.move').focus();

    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {

      $(".move:focus").closest('.subtaskDetailDive').prev().find('.move').focus();

    }
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="InsertDiv">
  <div draggable="true" data-serial="6018" ondragstart="drag(event,6018)" class="subtaskDetailDive complete" id="subtaskDetailDive6018">
    <div class="subtaskRow" id="readOnlyID6018">
      <textarea class='move'></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div draggable="true" data-serial="6019" ondragstart="drag(event,6019)" class="subtaskDetailDive complete" id="subtaskDetailDive6019">
    <div class="subtaskRow" id="readOnlyID6019">
      <textarea class='move'></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div draggable="true" data-serial="6020" ondragstart="drag(event,6020)" class="subtaskDetailDive complete" id="subtaskDetailDive6020">
    <div class="subtaskRow" id="readOnlyID6020">
      <textarea class='move'></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div draggable="true" data-serial="6021" ondragstart="drag(event,6021)" class="subtaskDetailDive complete" id="subtaskDetailDive6021">
    <div class="subtaskRow" id="readOnlyID6021">
      <textarea class='move'></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div draggable="true" data-serial="6022" ondragstart="drag(event,6022)" class="subtaskDetailDive complete" id="subtaskDetailDive6022">
    <div class="subtaskRow" id="readOnlyID6022">
      <textarea class='move'></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to write jQuery code

```
$('.subtaskRow textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 38){ // Key code for Up key
      $(".subtaskRow textarea:focus").closest('.subtaskDetailDive').prev().find('.subtaskRow textarea').focus();
      console.log("Up key Pressed");
    }      
    else if(e.keyCode == 40){ // Key code for Down key
      $(".subtaskRow textarea:focus").closest('.subtaskDetailDive').next().find('.subtaskRow textarea').focus();
      console.log("Down key Pressed");
    }
});
```

Refer this js fiddle link for output 
https://jsfiddle.net/z7kgmpz4/3/